# why I can't Identify two variable at the same line

Tags: python

I want to identify the variable g and h at the same line

g, h = eval(input("enter an integer: "))

print(g,h)

Comment: and what is the second variable supposed to take? Why use eval in this case?

Comment: I want to take an integer value from the user and give it to the variables

Comment: `int` is just one value, what's the second one?

Using eval is useless here, since you are not running a code from string

Comment: Or do you want both g and h to equal the same thing, which is what the user inputted?

Comment: yes i can't only  send yes so yes i want to do that

Comment: why not g = h = eval(input("enter an integer: "))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello leena and welcome to Stack Overflow,
As many noted, your could go follow multiple paths to achieve what you are looking for, as the Zen of Python says:

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
> Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.

The first suggestion is to split the the inputs as @arbyys says:

```py
g = input("Enter an integer: ")
h = input("Enter an integer: ")
```

Altought it won't  be the DRYest solution of the bunch.
If you are going to prefer a more functional approach you can 'force' the user to insert two inputs like this:

```py
def get_integers():
    return [input("Enter an integer: ") for _ in range(2)]

g,h = get_integers()
```

As for your eval, that's a very unsafe practice and you must avoid it in your programming, if you use it to type-cast the input value, you know they HAVE TO BE integers, so you can cast an int, in the following way:

```py
def get_integers():
    return [int(input("Enter an integer: ")) for _ in range(2)]

g,h = get_integers()
```

Obviously this would throw an error if you insert a non-integer as your input.

Edit:

If you want to give the same value to different variables you can go this route:

```py
g = h  = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
```

Comment: thank I think I will just define every variable in one line

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to enter more values, I suggest using list.

```py
values = []
for x in range(2):
  values.append(input("Enter value:"))
```

Then you can iterate over the list values.

If you want to avoid list, you can just give each variable its own input.

```
g = input("Enter first value:")
h = input("Enter second value:")
print(g,h)
```

Also, avoid using `eval` from user input, as it can cause some serious trouble in your code.

Comment: or use list map int to get multiple values at once

Comment: sorry sorry I made a mistake I wanted to put numbers not names

Comment: It doesn't matter, you can put whatever you want. If you want your variable to be integer, you just convert the input using `int(input("Enter number:"))`

Comment: thanks for your guidance it is highly appreciated